# tex4ht: custom list of … (part 2 of 3)

Tags: table-of-contents, tex4ht, htlatex

This is a direct follow-up to [tex4ht: custom list of .... (part 1 of 2)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/392656/tex4ht-custom-list-of-toc-related/392682?noredirect=1#comment975880_392682)

I have a custom list of `<things>`. The code below provides a link from each item in `List of cmh` to its place on the page. I would like (in the html version) for each occurrence of the output of `\cmhcommand` to link to its relevant place in the `List of cmh`.

### `mwe.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cmhloc}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{normal section}
\cmhcommand{Here is some text}
some text
\section{another secton}
\cmhcommand{Another text}
\cmhcommand{some more}

\listofcmh
\end{document}
```

### `cmhloc.sty`

```
\ProvidesPackage{cmhloc}
\newcommand{\cmhcommand}[1]{\addcontentsline{cmh}{subsection}{#1}#1}
\newcommand{\listofcmh}{\subsection*{List of cmh}\@starttoc{cmh}}
\endinput
```

### `cmhloc.4ht`

```
\ConfigureToc{cmh}{\HCode{<div class="sectionToc">}}{~}{}{\HCode{</div>\Hnewline}} 
\renewcommand\listofcmh{\subsection*{List of cmh}\TableOfContents[cmh]}
\endinput
```

The compilation I use to generate the `html` version is

```
htlatex mwe.tex
```

Comment: Should be the content of `\cmhcommand` be part of paragraph, or can it act like an section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, we need to construct unique id for each `\cmhcommand`, which will serve as link to the TOC. We will modify the `sty` file slightly:

```
\ProvidesPackage{cmhloc}
\newcommand\printcmhentry[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\cmhcommand}[1]{\addcontentsline{cmh}{subsection}{#1}\printcmhentry{#1}}
\newcommand{\listofcmh}{\subsection*{List of cmh}\@starttoc{cmh}}
\endinput
```

In this way, we need to redefine only the `\printcmhentry` command, without need to duplicate the logic of `\cmhcommand` in the `4ht` file:

```
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\def\toccmh#1#2#3{%
  \bgroup% make the changes local
    \Configure{TocLink}{% This will print the link in TOC.
      \Link{##2}{\@nameuse{cmhcn-##4}}##4\EndLink% We need to  construct the ID parameter in second parameter for \Link
    }
    \HCode{<div class="sectionToc">}#2\HCode{</div>\Hnewline}% Print the entry
  \egroup%
}%


\newcount\cmhcount % each cmhentry will have it's unique idntifier
\renewcommand\printcmhentry[1]{%
  \advance\cmhcount by1\relax%
  \edef\cmhlink{cmh-\the\cmhcount}% this will be the id for the corresponding entry in the \listcmh
  \csxdef{cmhcn-#1}{\cmhlink}\Link{\cmhlink}{}#1\EndLink} % we use the entry text in csname, 
                                                          % in order to be able to retrieve the id later
                                                          % in the \listcmh entries

\append:def\listofcmh{\TableOfContents[cmh]}
\endinput
```

In this case, `\toccmh` macro is defined instead of `\ConfigureToc{cmh}`, it is more flexible. We use `\Configure{TocLink}` to configure the hyperlinks in the TOC entries, the first argument is id of the `\addcontentsline`, the second one is anchor for the entry. `\@nameuse{cmhcn-##4}` exapnds to `\nameuse{cmhcn-Here is some text}` for example. This macro is defined in `\renewcommand\printcmhentry` and it contains the id the text links to.

This is the result:

```html
<h3 class="sectionHead"><span class="titlemark">1   </span>  <a 
 id="x1-20001"></a>normal section</h3>
<a 
 id="x1-2001"></a>
<!--l. 9--><p class="noindent" ><a 
href="#cmh-1">Here is some text</a> some text
</p>
   <h3 class="sectionHead"><span class="titlemark">2   </span>  <a 
 id="x1-30002"></a>another secton</h3>
<a 
 id="x1-3001"></a>
<!--l. 13--><p class="noindent" ><a 
href="#cmh-2">Another text</a>
</p><!--l. 16--><p class="indent" >   Inside paragraph: <a 
 id="x1-3002"></a><a 
href="#cmh-3">some more</a>. It doesn’t work well.
</p><!--l. 25--><p class="noindent" >
</p>
   <h4 class="likesubsectionHead"> <a 
 id="x1-40002"></a>List of cmh</h4>
   <div class="tableofcontents"> <div class="sectionToc"><a 
href="#x1-2001" id="cmh-1">Here is some text</a></div> 
 <div class="sectionToc"><a 
href="#x1-3001" id="cmh-2">Another text</a></div> 
 <div class="sectionToc"><a 
href="#x1-3002" id="cmh-3">some more</a></div> 

   </div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much indeed, this is exactly what I need! I hope you'll accept the small bounties I've awarded on this and the other question as tokens of my thanks. I'll award them after a few days, in an attempt to maximise exposure. Thanks again!

Comment: I am glad that it works for you. It was interesting exercise in digging in tex4ht sources, because this stuff isn't really well documented. Documentation is worst pain of tex4ht, I am not really good in writing :( And really thanks for the bounties, I really appreciate it.

Comment: no worries :) In case you're interested, the final use case is here: http://users.mct.open.ac.uk/chris.hughes/sonification-phase1-report/final_report.html in particular, the `Figure description` command uses your code :)

Comment: @cmhughes it is actually quite interesting topic. I have only few comments: you should use different address for MathJax script, the `cdn.mathjax.org` is abandoned. I guess that the old address is still advertised somewhere in my older posts.

Comment: @cmhughes I think there is a issue with configuration for `\textbf` and `\textit` commands, because `<b>` and `<i>` tags are sometimes outside paragraphs. see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66172/2891 for more information

Comment: @cmhughes it might be also interesting to use [ARIA](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA) to help the disabled readers. `tex4ht` doesn't have support for it yet, but it would be nice to work on it.

Comment: thanks again for all of your help. If I can trespass on your time a little further, I've posted a follow-up: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/460907/tex4ht-custom-list-of-part-2-of-3