# htlatex: incorrect minitoc when using custom list of <things>

Tags: table-of-contents, tex4ht, htlatex

This question is a follow-up to [tex4ht: custom list of … (part 2 of 2)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/392824/tex4ht-custom-list-of-part-2-of-2)

I'm using `htlatex` to produce `html` on a one-subsection-per-page basis. I'm also using the technique described in the post linked above to produce a custom list of `<things>`. The two methods are, it appears, interfering with one another, as demonstrated in the following minimum working example.

### `mwe.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{figuredescriptions}
\begin{document}

\section{First section}

\subsection{subsection}
\figuredescription{Figure description needed: 9}

\figuredescription{Figure description needed: 10}

\subsection{another subsection}

\section{Second section}

section text

\subsection{a subsection}

subsection text

\listofdesc

\end{document}
```

### `ht-mwe.cfg`

```
\Preamble{xhtml,3}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

### `figuredescriptions.sty`

```
\ProvidesPackage{figuredescriptions}
\newcommand\printdescentry[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\figuredescription}[1]{\addcontentsline{desc}{subsection}{#1}\printdescentry{#1}}
\newcommand{\listofdesc}{\section{List of figure descriptions}\@starttoc{desc}}
\endinput
```

The file `figuredescriptions.4ht` is not necessary to demonstrate the problem.

Upon running the command

```
 htlatex mwe.tex "ht-mwe.cfg"
```

then I receive the following output:

[image: screenshot of incorrect output]

Notice that the 'minitoc' for section 2 is not correct.

I can get round this by not having a `minitoc` by using `\Preamble{xhtml,3,nominitoc}` but perhaps in the future I'd actually quite like a (correct!) minitoc on a per-section basis.

### the question

How can I amend the code above so that `minitoc`s on a per-section basis are correct in the `html` output?

Comment: This is indeed strange issue, I've not found the solution yet, I will investigate it more tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that this issue is caused by manual `\addtocontentsline` used in `\figuredescription` command. Some counters needs to be updated in this case. I've found the following note in `tex4ht` sources:

> Tex4ht relies on two counters `'\TitleCount' and `'\TocCount' to
>   decide which entries of the global TOC should go to the local TOC.
>   The first counter is increased when sectioning commands are
>   encountered. The second counter is increased when the global TOC is
>   traversed.
>
> A discrepancy will occur when the contributions of the sectioning
>   commands to the global TOC are not synchronized with the increments of
>   the first counter.  That will normally be the case when sectioning
>   commands are introduced without tex4h being informed about their
>   designation as sectioning commands.

As I understand it, it is necessary to update the `\TitleCount` counter manually. For example by appending the following code to `figuredescription.4ht`:

```
\pend:defI\figuredescription{\gHAdvance\TitleCount  1\relax}
```

The `\pend:defI` command will insert code at the beginning of command with one argument. I've found the code `\gHAdvance\TitleCount  1` in the various places in `tex4ht` source code.

The TOC seems to be correct now:

[image]

Note that I've added `\TocAt{section,subsection}` to the .cfg file to request the TOC before the section text.

Comment: Many thanks indeed for this, it's wonderful. I've found your answers and knowledge of `tex4ht` to be invaluable. I've also still failed to find a comprehensive source of documentation (other than grepping the source) -- I would be interested in collaborating in constructing a 'readthedocs' for `htlatex`, perhaps via `GitHub`, is this something you'd be interested in? (Obviously I don't have anywhere near as much knowledge in `htlatex` as you, but I do have experience in writing documentation)

Comment: @cmhughes thanks for your kind words. Regarding the documentation, I've set up basic outline for a new documentation [here](http://svn.gnu.org.ua/viewvc/tex4ht/trunk/doc/tex4ht-doc/). As you can see, I update it only sparingly, I would definitely welcome some help. I can move it to Github if it would enable easier collaboration, I understand that SVN and our current source repository are not as user friendly.

Comment: I'd be very happy to try to contribute as much as I can, although I freely admit to not being an expert in tex4ht -- perhaps that might be an advantage, for the kinds of examples I would contribute. The format is up to you, but I'd certainly express a preference for Github. Have you seen Sphinx, which can be directly plugged in to readthedocs? MathJax uses it, and I've used it for latexindent as well; it seems to work well

Comment: @cmhughes I think tex4ht expertise is not that important, some feedback is always welcome, for example regarding writing style, if everything is understandable, providing LaTeX examples, etc. I will set up Github repo then. I want to keep the documentation in LaTeX, main reason is to provide  an example of complex document produced by tex4ht with lot of custom configurations and macros.

Comment: @cmhughes I've created a Github repo for the documentation: https://github.com/michal-h21/tex4ht-doc

Comment: ace! :) I've opened an issue :)