# tex4ht: custom list of … (part 3 of 3)

Tags: table-of-contents, tex4ht, htlatex

This is a direct follow-up to [tex4ht: custom list of … (part 2 of 3)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/392824/tex4ht-custom-list-of-part-2-of-3)

I have a custom list of `<things>`. The code below provides two-way links between the occurrence of the `<thing>` on the page and its place in the `List of cmh`.

### the question

How can I adapt the solution from the linked question to account for cases in which the argument to `\cmhcommand` contains either or both of the following:

- multiple paragraphs
- mathematical content

To reproduce the problem in the code below, replace `\cmhcommand{Here is some text}` with `\cmhcommand{Here is some text\par a new paragraph}` in `mwe.tex`.

### `mwe.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cmhloc}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{normal section}
\cmhcommand{Here is some text}
some text
\section{another secton}
\cmhcommand{Another text}
\cmhcommand{some more}

\listofcmh
\end{document}
```

### `cmhloc.sty`

```
\ProvidesPackage{cmhloc}
\newcommand\printcmhentry[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\cmhcommand}[1]{\addcontentsline{cmh}{subsection}{#1}\printcmhentry{#1}}
\newcommand{\listofcmh}{\subsection*{List of cmh}\@starttoc{cmh}}
\endinput
```

### `cmhloc.4ht`

```
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\def\toccmh#1#2#3{%
  \bgroup% make the changes local
    \Configure{TocLink}{% This will print the link in TOC.
      \Link{##2}{\@nameuse{cmhcn-##4}}##4\EndLink% We need to  construct the ID parameter in second parameter for \Link
    }
    \HCode{<div class="sectionToc">}#2\HCode{</div>\Hnewline}% Print the entry
  \egroup%
}%


\newcount\cmhcount % each cmhentry will have it's unique idntifier
\renewcommand\printcmhentry[1]{%
  \advance\cmhcount by1\relax%
  \edef\cmhlink{cmh-\the\cmhcount}% this will be the id for the corresponding entry in the \listcmh
  \csxdef{cmhcn-#1}{\cmhlink}\Link{\cmhlink}{}#1\EndLink} % we use the entry text in csname, 
                                                          % in order to be able to retrieve the id later
                                                          % in the \listcmh entries

\append:def\listofcmh{\TableOfContents[cmh]}
\endinput
```

### `compilation sequence`

`htlatex mwe.tex`

Comment: Picky minimalism, but wouldn't this be "part 3 of 3"? :-)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik for sure :) thanks for that, apologies for the mistake :)

Comment: I don't think it is possible to use the paragraphs in TOC, but inline math seems to work.